# Convert bzr repo to git? Fast-export no longer supported?

Tags: git, bazaar

I still have some archives in bzr format, and I would like to convert the remaining ones to git. I have done it previously using

```
git init .
bzr fast-export . | git fast-import
```

but that doesn't work anymore, the fastimport plugin hasn't been ported to Python3 and when going back to Ubuntu 18.04, the fastimport plugin throws a TypeError exception in bzrlib.

I bazaar completely abandoned? It seems very surprising since Launchpad.net is based on it.

PS: I am running 20.04

Answer (score 1):

Bazaar has not been pointed to Python 3 either. You could Bazaar and bzr-fastimport with Python 2.

Alternatively, there is Breezy (https://www.breezy-vcs.org/), a fork of Bazaar that has been ported to Python 3 and that bundles the fastexport plugin. This is in Ubuntu as the "brz" package.

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering why I couldn't find anything on DuckDuckGo about updates to Bazaar to Python3. I now found out that Breezy is installed as both bzr and brz on my system since bzr is a dummy package and /etc/alternatives/bzr -> /usr/bin/brz. You say that the fastexport plugin is bundled, however, I get this when trying: brz: ERROR: unknown command "fast-export".

Comment: Solved it! I had to remove the fastimport plugin from my ~/.bazaar/plugins directory. Thanks again!